# Snap to grid in millimeters on a panel?

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+

I have a panel. I need to represent it in [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG).

Now, when *drawing* on it, is possible to draw using millimeters instead of pixels.

```
graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter
graphics.DrawRectangle(pen,rect)
```

Is it possible to *position the controls*(buttons, textboxes) also in millimeters, in order to get a "real" paper image of the panel?

In VB6 this was possible. Is .NET a step backward or VB6 just use the approximation that we don't want to use in .NET?

Comment: Why not take the DPI and convert from inches to millimeters?

Comment: Monitor DPI will tell you how many dots (pixels) per inch are on the screen. If you want measurements to come out correctly, take your desired millimeters / 25.4 (to convert to inches) * DPI. This will tell you how many pixels you need.

Comment: would you elaborate? I don't need to convert in inches, but millimeters, however, the problem remains the same. Say, I have to position a textBox at 5x5 mm from the upper top corner. `myTextBox.Location = ??` DPI should mean **DOTS** per inch, not **Pixels** per inch.

Comment: You're right, I don't believe this is possible after all. DPI is useful for printing, and while it can be used for screen layout, I don't believe you can get exact measurements without knowing the Pixel Density for the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till this, an acceptable solution:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ffb7e52d-8533-465c-bd57-17f7b704c927

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, I don't believe this is possible, without performing specific math for each monitor you support.

DPI is commonly used for printing, and is useful for measurements on paper. However, measurements on a monitor are not guaranteed, since you can change resolutions at any time and still have the same DPI (typically 96). Beyond that you need to also consider monitor size.

What you need to know is the [Pixel Density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density), or PPI, for your specific monitor. I don't believe this can be obtained, although others can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: hm. So what, VB6 is more powerful that VB.NET?

Comment: Should the measurements be accurate in terms of printing size or screen size? I'm not sure how VB6 works exactly, but from what I'm seeing on Google, VB6's measurements are only accurate for printing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dpiX = Graphics.DpiX;//horizontal
var dpiY = Graphics.DpiY;//vertical

var mmX = (width_in_pixles * 25.4 ) / dpiX;
var mmY = (height_in_pixles * 25.4) / dpiY;
```

There are 25.4 mm in 1 inch so using the above formulas you can calculate heights and widths of controls in mm and adjust their positions also.

Comment: DPI should mean **DOTS** per inch, not **Pixels** per inch.